# Bookmarklet/JavaScript to rotate URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want to create a Bookmarklet which will load one link out of a list of ten links, order doesn't matter, but weight-age does.

I tried http://www.htmlbasix.com/textrotator.shtml but it's for rotating a link on a webpage, how to make a Bookmarklet which will open a random URL from the list? Kind of URL rotator script within a bookmark.

Any efficient way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't setup bookmarklet to run automatically. Consider writing browser extension or just use `curl`.

> Not automatically.

Then it varies.

First, if you're 100% that pages don't redirect you anywhere you can try to use `window.location` inside you bookmarklet in next way:

```
var next = urls.indexOf(window.location.href) + 1;
next = next < urls.length ? next : 0;
window.location = urls[next];
```

If one of pages redirects or messes with url then you can use `localStorage` on your own domain and `postMessage` to store any data between bookmarklet calls.

Comment: Not automatically. Basically I want to create a bookmark, which when I click for the first time opens first link, on second click opens second link, on third click opens third link and so on....

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution after few tries

```
javascript: (function randomlinks() {
    var myrandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    var links = new Array();
    links[0] = "http://www.javascriptkit.com";
    links[1] = "http://www.dynamicdrive.com";
    links[2] = "http://www.cssdrive.com";
    links[3] = "http://www.codingforums.com";
    links[4] = "http://www.news.com";
    links[5] = "http://www.gamespot.com";
    links[6] = "http://www.msnbc.com";
    links[7] = "http://www.cnn.com";
    links[8] = "http://news.bbc.co.uk";
    links[9] = "http://www.news.com.au";

    window.location = links[myrandom];
  })()
```